# Flash Media Gateway with SIP refer

Tags: apache-flex, sip, flex4.5, flash-media-server

I am trying to find out if the Flash Media Gateway (an add-on for Flash Media Server that supports Telephony integration) is capable of supporting the SIP REFER verb.  In the current environment we have set up, whenever a SIP REFER message is received by the gateway, the call ends up being dropped without anything of not showing up in the error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally received an answer from Adobe directly on this one:

> Currently, Flash Media Gateway doesn't support receiving REFER and
>   these are not included in allow header.